# Error on line 1, column 1 of pubspec.lock: Unexpected character

Tags: flutter, dart, yaml, cross-platform

I tried to run `flutter pub get` and I got this error:

```
Error on line 1, column 1 of pubspec.lock: Unexpected character
╷

1 │
│ ^

  ╵
pub upgrade failed (65;   ╵)
```

Comment: try running `flutter clean`

Comment: flutter clean does not modify `pubspec.lock`, it just deletes `build` folder. Try removing `pubspec.lock` and run `flutter pub get` again.

Comment: check your pubspec file. There must be '|' charactor available. remove it and flutter pub get again!

Answer (score 17):

The file pubspec.lock is a generated file, so you can delete it and then regenerate it.

Delete **pubspec.lock**.

Run the following command:

```
flutter pub get
```

or

```
flutter pub upgrade
```

Notes on [pub upgrade](https://dart.dev/tools/pub/cmd/pub-upgrade) (you could probably skip the delete step).

Answer (score 2):

Delete the file at flutter/packages/flutter_tools/pubspec.lock then try flutter pub upgrade again.

You may have interrupted the upgrade process before it finished hence the file became invalid.

Answer (score 2):

I got the same error while working.

I deleted **pubspec.lock** file.

then I ran command

`flutter pub get`

It created new **pubspec.lock** file.

Now application runs without any errors.

Answer (score 1):

I took the same error,
but this error was coming from my main folder.
in this path "C:\Users"yourusername"\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\global_packages\devtools"
I deleted the file and I started app. file has been by itself created and problem solved.